# Move data file on oracle db like mssql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, database-administration

For a client application, I would like to manage different DBs, depending to data I would like to use in a particular moment.
I can't change the code of application, and I've found a solution really pretty for MSSQL, but I need to replicate it also with Oracle DB.
Please consider that the application has an "hardcoded" connection to DB (name and host).

With MSSQL, I've found this solution starting from collection different datafiles for the same DB (called XXDB), each datafile contains different data, so I can easily change data in this way:

- Switch off the application
- I detach the DB from SQL
- Now I can move mdf and ldf files
- Insert other mdf and ldf files
- Attach the DB using the other mdf and ldf files
- Restart the application

In this way I'm able to change quickly the data used for application testing.

I would like to replicate this simple path on Oracle DB 10g, is that possible?

Do I need to evaluate other solution to switch data mantaining the same name and user to connect to DB?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The closest analogue would be to use [transportable tablespaces](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/transportable-tablespaces.php) assuming that all the objects are in one (or more) self-contained tablespaces.  Though the process is broadly similar to what you're doing in SQL Server, it's not going to be nearly as seamless in Oracle.  Transportable tablespaces were designed to let you efficiently move very large quantities of data from one database to another, not for this sort of thing.

How much data are we talking about?  Using DataPump to export and import the data as needed may well be an easier solution that doesn't sacrifice much performance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify: your code *already* connects to and works against an Oracle database, you just need a solution to change around the source data in Oracle for testing?

The backend of Oracle is far more complicated than SQL and I suggest you forget about automating Oracle datafiles to get different datasets.

The normal way to change datasets for testing is to point your app a different instance/database/user, rather than hard coding a conection in the app. As it is, an Oracle connection string is totally different to a SQL connection string so you already need to change the connection details in your App to do this.

Comment: I just can't believe that you would have an app that is mature enough to seamlessly work against SQL and Oracle, but not mature enough to be able to change the connection on the fly?